# Probability of exclusive and exhaustive events

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

If $A, B$ and $C$ are three mutually exclusive and exhaustive events and $$2\Pr(A) = 3 \Pr(B) = 4 \Pr(C).$$ Find $\Pr(A \cup B)$.

Comment: To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck. Our aim is to improve your mathematical skills.

Comment: On top of your own efforts you should add your background and knowledge, including the definition of the keywords used here. If you don't know them, you should look them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=P(A),y=P(B)$ and $z=P(C)$, you have to solve the linear system

$x+y+z=1$

$2x-3y=0$

$2x-4z=0$.

It is your turn to show that $x=\frac{6}{13}, y=\frac{4}{13}$ and $z=\frac{3}{13}$.

Hence $P(A \cup B)=x+y=\frac{10}{13}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using the *mutually exclusive and exhaustive* information, you have three equations in three unknowns

$$2 \mathbb P (A) = 3 \mathbb P (B)$$
$$3 \mathbb P (B) = 4 \mathbb P (C)$$
$$\mathbb P (A) + \mathbb P (B) + \mathbb P (C) =\mathbb P (A \cup B \cup C)= 1$$

so you can solve these. (You also know $2 \mathbb P (A) =  4 \mathbb P (C)$ and $\mathbb P (A) \ge 0$, $\mathbb P (B)\ge 0$, $\mathbb P (C)\ge 0$ though these do not add information here)

You then want $\mathbb P (A \cup B) =\mathbb P (A) + \mathbb P (B)$

Comment: Is the answer 10/13?

Comment: @AayushMukharji -  I would have thought so, though you are supposed to show your working

Comment: According to book answer is 7/3 and my answer doesn't match.

Comment: $\mathbb P (A \cup B)$ is a probability and so cannot be greater than $1$.  Not much help but $\frac7{13}=\mathbb P (B \cup C)$

Comment: @AayushMukharji If the book says that the probability is $7/3$, then that is clearly an error because probabilities can only be between $0$ and $1$, and $7/3 > 1$.

Comment: Yeah I also thought so I tried a lot but answer wasn't matching thanks for confirming.